# How to delete an items inside a list nested by a field

Tags: c#, list, collections, nested, removeall

I have a problem with a deletion in a list.

Imagine this 2 records like this.

**Item1: ID = 1001, Name="A", Dependency = 1, Order=1.00**

**Item2: ID = 2354, Name="B", Dependency = 1, Order=1.01**

They are linked in some way by the dependency and visual effect in the web page is like an element nested by another one. I've been trying to delete this record in the front-end. Database level is ok. This thing is in order to avoid the database roundtrip I used to delete the element from my collection and do a databind refresh. But now, with my element nested I don't know have to do it.

I tried this in a rush without seeing the problem of list modification.

```
        this.Entity.Items.Remove(this.CurrentItem);
        foreach(Item item in this.Entity.Items)
        {
            if(item.Dependency == this.CurrentItem.Depedency){
                this.Entity.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        myRepeater.DataSource = this.Entity.Items
        myRepeater.DataBind();
```

Then I did

```
        this.Entity.Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Depedency == this.CurrentItem.Dependency);
        myRepeater.DataSource = this.Entity.Items
        myRepeater.DataBind();
```

But ToList() recreates a new list and this do not remove anything in the same list
Items is a collection (List) inside the Entity

Not allow to modify entities structures nor databases, please.

Comment: What is `Entity`, what is `Item`, have you overridden `Equals`?

Comment: Also what type is `Items` and why you restricted yourself to modifying them in-place?

Comment: Entity is object like Person and Items is a collection inside that object i.e.  Person.Childs. No, I've not overriden Equals. Item is a singular from that collection. foreach(Child child in Person.Childs)

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: Then override it and you'll be happy.

Comment: Geeh man, thanks a lot ... if I knew how to do it, I didn't ask this question! Any help please

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop instead of a for each.

Also, you can try

```
myRepeater.DataSource = this.Entity.Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Depedency == this.CurrentItem.Dependency);
```